# Activity variable in a static function

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, android-context

I am writing an Android app where I am trying to run the Facebook.authorize function. This function takes the following arguments:

```
Facebook.authorize(Activity, DialogListener());
```

Now, when I make this call in a static function, I tried passing a "Context" variable in the call like this:

```
public static void dummyFunction(Context context)
{
    Facebook.authorize(context, new DialogListener(){});
}
```

And I make the call like so:

```
dummyfunction(this);
```

When I do all of that, I get the error:

```
The function Facebook.authorize(Context, DialogListener) is not applicable for the arguments Facebook.authorize(Activity, Dialoglistener).
```

Please tell me how I can pass a static "Activity" variable in this case.

Comment: What happens if you change the signature to `public static void dummyFunction(Activity activity)` and still pass `this`?

Comment: Didn't think of that. Did it and no more errors now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
public static void dummyFunction(Activity activity)
{
    Facebook.authorize(activity, new DialogListener(){});
}
```

and calling it

```
dummy(this);
```

?

Comment: This was suggested by another person and it worked. No more errors. Thanks for your answer. :)